# Preg_replace with array element

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I have array like below:

```
function func($name){
    $arr = [
      'dog' => 'boo|pet|chinsu|lu',
      'man' => 'david|peter|john|smith',
      'woman' => 'marry|daisy|anna|tailor'
    ];
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $name = preg_replace("/($v)/i",$k,$name);
    }
    return $name;
}

echo func('john'); //return 'man' => OK
echo func('peter');  //return 'doger' => Not OK
```

It should return 'man' instead of 'doger', but 'pet' also exist in 'peter'.

How can I fix this but still using preg_replace?

Comment: I would put the boundary markers and the regex delimiter and options in `$arr`, making each value a `regex`. This way the code is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add word boundary `\b` in your regex:

```
$name = preg_replace("/\b$v\b/i", $k, $name);
//              here __^^  ^^
```

Comment: That's right, but has small fix: $name=preg_replace("/\b($v)\b/i",$k,$name); This's work for me. Thank you!